# Is there a way to add hooks in VSCode actions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, plugins, terminal, hook, add-on

Is there a way to add hooks in some particular action of that editor?

For example:

When I start a terminal, executes a script (preferably bashscript like git does).

When I kill a terminal execute another bashscript file (hook).

PS.: I don't want to develop a new extension, I'm looking for something more simple like a configuration of the editor. Public extensions are accepted as answer if does a similar feature but I didn't found out one that does it. Maybe that question can be a suggestion for a new feature.

Comment: There are hooks through out V.S. Code, but its not like there is a hook setting that automatically knows what and where you want to hook to. The community members that often answer the VS Code questions are able to tell  you how to hook to something, but you got to help  them out by letting them know what it is you want to hook to.

Comment: @JAY-DEV, I would be glad to open a feature request VSCode if they want to. As I said, the hook would be linked with the action to open and kill a terminal.

Comment: IDK why opening a feature request is relative to the context of my previous comment, but w/e. So you want to hook, when the console is created, or killed. Don't think there is a hook for that, unless your using it for debugging purposes, then you can use the pre-launch hook, and post-launch hook in the `launch.json` file, which allows devs to hook a task. I been playing with it so it changes the consoles name while I am debugging. Any hooks of that sort would be referenced in the VSCode tasks documentation.